# Can someone prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality, but I cannot.

Can someone help me?

I'll appreciate any small hints.

$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log_2k \le \frac12 n^2 \log_2n - \frac18 n^2
$$

Comment: I think you try induction first and see some properties through it, then you rework the proof.

Comment: you mean, mathematical induction? 1. base 2. assume k 3. k+1? okay thank you!!

Comment: Note that $\int x \log_2(x) dx = \frac{x^2\log(x)}{2} -\frac{x^2}{4} + C$

The asymptotic expansions  using [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) should be useful here.

Comment: Thank you for a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**:

Follow the professor's hint and the above comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} k\log_2k\leq \displaystyle \int_{2}^n x\log_2xdx$. The right side should come out from this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got a lot of help.

Answer (score 1):

I am really appreciate many hints and advice.
Thanks to them, I could success proving this proposition state.

---

Prove that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log_2k \le \frac12n^2 \log_2n-\frac18n^2
$$

---

Proof:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} k \log_{2}{k} &\le \int_{2}^{n} x \log_{2}{x} {dx}\\
&=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}{\log_2x}\right]_{2}^{n} - \int_{2}^{n} \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{1}{x\ln2}dx\\
&=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}{\log_2x}\right]_{2}^{n} - \int_{2}^{n} \frac{x}{2\ln2}dx\\
&=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}{\log_2x}\right]_{2}^{n} - \left[\frac{x^2}{4\ln2}\right]_{2}^{n}\\
&=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}{\log_2x} - \frac{x^2}{4\ln2}\right]_{2}^{n}\\
&=\left[\frac{n^2}{2}{\log_2n} - \frac{n^2}{4\ln2}\right] - \left[2 - \frac{1}{\ln2}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}{n^2}{\log_2n} - \frac{n^2}{4\ln2} - 2 + \frac{1}{\ln2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}{n^2}{\log_2n} - \frac{1}{8}n^2\left(\frac{2}{\ln2}+\frac{16}{n^2}-\frac{8}{n^2\ln2}\right)
\end{align*}

---

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{\ln2}+\frac{16}{n^2}-\frac{8}{n^2\ln2} &\ge 1\\
\frac{2n^2+16\ln2-8}{n^2\ln2} &\ge 1\\
2n^2+16\ln2-8 &\ge n^2\ln2\\
(2-\ln2)n^2 &\ge 8(1-2\ln2) = 8\left(\ln\frac{e}{4}\right)\\\\\\
\therefore \frac{2}{\ln2}+\frac{16}{n^2}-\frac{8}{n^2\ln2} &\ge 1\\
\big(\because (2-\ln2)n^2 &\gt 0 , \ \ \  8\left(\ln\frac{e}{4}\right) \lt 0\big)
\end{align*}

---

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log_2k &\le \int_{2}^{n} x \log_{2}{x} {dx}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}{n^2}{\log_2n} - \frac{1}{8}n^2\left(\frac{2}{\ln2}+\frac{16}{n^2}-\frac{8}{n^2\ln2}\right)\\
&\le \frac12n^2 \log_2n-\frac18n^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Try bounding the sum by an integral.  Note that $k \log_2 k$ is an increasing function on $[2,\infty)$

Comment: can you explain a liitle more about the bounding sum by an integral? you meean $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)dx$ ?

Answer (score 0):

[Summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) gives:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log_2 k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\left(\log_2(k+1)-\log_2(k)\right) $$
but since $\log_2(1+x)$ is a concave function on $[0,1]$, we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log_2 k \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log_2(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+1}{2} $$
hence:

> $$ \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k\log_2 k \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}\log_2(n) - \frac{(n+2)(n-1)}{4}.$$